# Get values form a single row using a tabutalor on button click

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am somehow new to javascript and to his plugins, and for this web app I am trying to create a button that gets one single row from tabulator(plugin), but the problem here is I only can do it once every time I refresh the page otherwise the result is the same as the first one, and I don't want that. Keep in mind this tabulator is in a modal view.

To get the data I am doing this:

```
var tab_modal = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#modal-table')[0];
    var data_modal = tab_modal.getData()[0];
```

and for the first time works fine but the secund the value doesn't change.
I went out and search a little bit I found this [solution](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/938) but came out with a error `$("...").Tabulator is not a function`.

Can someone help me??

Sorry for the bad english.

Thanks in advance

this is the all button code

```
$("#modal-btn").on('click', function (e) {

    var tab_modal = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#modal-table')[0];
    var data_modal = tab_modal.getData()[0];
    console.log(data_modal);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "....",
        datatype: 'json',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "...",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: { ... },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        get_list(tree);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to clarify I wanted to store and use the values from the row in one table that was in a modal view, but what was happening was that I only code store on time, everytime I repeated the process I couldn´t change the val previous setted up  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlAmR.png)

so instead of trying to store it after pressing the button I do it everytime I edit the cell using tabulator properties.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#modal-table", {
    reactiveData: true,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    resizableRows: true,
    data: data, 
    columns: [
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "title_name", field: "field_name", editor: "input" },
    ],
    cellEdited: function (cell) {

        var data = cell.getRow().getData();
        console.log(data);
        dados_row = [{ /* storing here the array so later I can use it */ }];
        console.log(dados_row)

    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `getData()[0]` is always going to get the first row.

You can do:

```
var row = getRow(<some_number>)
var data = row.getData()
```

where some_number is the index value for the row. The index would need to be defined in the table constructor as:

`index: index_fld`.

If this does not answer you question you will have to update the question to be more explicit about what data you want to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but didn´t I ended up resolving my self, again thanks

Comment: Then you should create your own answer so anyone that comes across this can see what you did. Or add it to your question.